# DatePicker on Button Press

Tags: react-native, button, datepicker

I am building a react-native application for iOS Devices and I would like to know how it is possible to have one button which onPress will load a DatePicker which will return the selected date?

Thank you.

Comment: https://github.com/xgfe/react-native-datepicker

Comment: But how to show the picker or button click?

Comment: What have you tried sofar?

Comment: [Follow this link for datetimepicker in class component](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71673878/14448694)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is how you can do it, you need to setState on button press simple

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import DatePicker from 'react-native-datepicker'

export default class MyDatePicker extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
     date:"2016-05-15",
     showPickerCheck: false
    },
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <View>
      <Button
       onPress={() => {this.showPicker()}}
       />
      {this.renderDatePicker()}
     </View>
    )
  }

showPicker = () => {
  if(this.state.showPickerCheck)  
     this.setState({showPickerCheck: false   
    })
  }else{
    this.setState({showPickerCheck: true   
    })
  }
}

renderDatePicker = () => {
   if(this.state.showPickerCheck){
     return(
       <DatePicker
        style={{width: 200}}
        date={this.state.date}
        mode="date"
        placeholder="select date"
        format="YYYY-MM-DD"
        minDate="2016-05-01"
        maxDate="2016-06-01"
        confirmBtnText="Confirm"
        cancelBtnText="Cancel"
        customStyles={{
          dateIcon: {
            position: 'absolute',
            left: 0,
            top: 4,
            marginLeft: 0
          },
          dateInput: {
            marginLeft: 36
          }
          // ... You can check the source to find the other keys.
        }}
        onDateChange={(date) => {this.setState({date: date})}}
      />
     )
   }else return null
  }
}
```

Comment: In addition to onDateChange you should also include an onSelect prop with the same setstate method.  I used datepicker without this and you run the issue of selecting the same date not registering which can cause issues if you set state to null initially and set date upon click or something.  Just a personal edge case observation.  Otherwise the response is good.

Comment: i dindt see still confirm button can you help me ?

Answer (score 1):

I have been round the houses with this and worked out that you need to wrap the datepicker in a modal in inline mode within ios. I am using DateTimePicker from '@react-native-community/datetimepicker' rather than react-native-datepicker

I have wrapped the string representation of the date object in a pressable that displays the 'show' property. When you press the pressable you get a modal with the calendar coming up in it, which disappears and sets the date when you click on a date.

I may have bodged a long way round but it seems to work

```
const [date, setDate] = useState(new Date());
const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

const onChange = (event, selectedDate) => {
    const currentDate = selectedDate || date;
    setShow(false);
    setDate(currentDate);
};
return (
<View>
        {show ?
            <Modal

                style={{backgroundColor: 'white', marginTop: 0}}
                animationType="fade"
                transparent={true}
                statusBarTranslucent={true}

            >
                <View style={
                    {
                        ...styles.centeredView,
                        backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6)',
                        marginTop: 120,
                        marginLeft: 20,
                        marginRight: 20,
                    }}>
                    <DateTimePicker
                        style={{backgroundColor: 'white'}}
                        testID="dateTimePicker"
                        value={date}
                        mode={"date"}
                        display="inline"
                        onChange={onChange}
                     
                    />
                </View>
            </Modal>
            :
            <Pressable onPress={() => setShow(true)}>
                <Text>
                    {date ? date.toLocaleDateString('en-GB') : 'select'}
                </Text>
            </Pressable>
        }
</View>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this was my solution:

NativeBase DatePicker:

```
 <DatePicker
              defaultDate={new Date(2018, 4, 4)}
              minimumDate={new Date(2018, 1, 1)}
              maximumDate={new Date(2020, 12, 31)}
              locale={"es"}
              timeZoneOffsetInMinutes={undefined}
              modalTransparent={true}
              animationType={"fade"}
              androidMode={"default"}
              placeHolderText="Select date"
              textStyle={{ color: "green" }}
              placeHolderTextStyle={{ color: "#d3d3d3" }}
              onDateChange={this.setDate.bind(this)}
              disabled={false}
              ref={c => this._datePicker = (c) } 
            />
```

And with this you can open the datePicker:

```
 <Button onPress={()=>{ this._datePicker.setState({modalVisible:true})}}>
   <Text>
  showDatePicker
  </Text>
</Button>
```